# Shuffle array variables in a pre-specified order, without using extra memory of "size of input array"

Tags: c++, algorithm

Input :

```
  A[4] = {0,4,-1,1000} - Actual Array
  P[4] = {1,0,3,2} - Order to be reshuffled
```

Output:

```
    A[4] = {4,0,1000,-1}
```

Condition : Don't use an additional array as memory. Can use an extra variable or two.

Problem : I have the below program in C++, but this fails for certain inputs of array P.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a_r,int *r)
{
    int temp = *r;
    *r = *a_r;
    *a_r = temp;
}
int main()
{
    int A[4] = {0,4,-1,1000};
    int P[4] = {3,0,1,2};
    int value = A[0] , dest = P[0];

    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        swap(&A[dest],&value);
        dest = P[dest];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::swap`?

Comment: can you provide a particular A and P for which this generates incorrect results?

Comment: @shuttle87 - dosen't shuffle the input P[4] = {1,0,3,2} , {3,2,1,0} .. Basically those inputs which have interchanged positions like {0-1} {1-2} etc...

Comment: Does each element of P specify the index of the A element that should end up in that position in the result? Or does each P value specify the destination where the corresponding A element should end up? In other words: does `result[x] = A[P[x]]` or does `result[P[x]] = A[x]`? The given example turns out to be the same either way, however that's not true for every P and so this affects the answer. At first glance I would have interpreted it the first way, but your code seems to be based on the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I really like **Jonathan**'s solution, but I feel like I can add some interesting ideas too.

The main observation is that array `P` consists of several loops.
Let's consider `p = {1, 4, 3, 2, 0, 5}`. There're three loops: `0 => 1 => 4 => 0`, `2 => 3 => 2` and `5 => 5`. And to replace variables alongside one loop we need no additional memory at all. We just go through it like this

```
do {
    a[i] = a[p[i]];
    i = p[i];
} while (i != first_i);
```

(The last element needs to be taken special care of, though.) The full working version:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (p[i] < 0) {
            // been at index 'i' already
            continue;
        }

        // new loop found
        int j = i;
        int first_value = a[i]; // to be put in last position in the chain
        int prev_j; // we always store previous 'j' index
        do {
            a[j] = a[p[j]];

            prev_j = j;
            j = p[j]; // move to next 'j'
            p[prev_j] = -1; // mark element as processed
        } while (i != j);
        a[prev_j] = first_value;
    }
```

The only problem with my solution is that it uses `p` array to mark element as 'processed'. Some interviewers may consider it ok, others - not, depending on the solution they have in mind.

Comment: If they don't like modifying P, you can add an additional function that checks if the cycle starting at i reaches a point j, such that j < i, if that is the case you already processed this cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've got a spare array called P kicking around, and there isn't anything in the question as quoted that stipulates it must be treated as a constant array, you could do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    P[i] = A[P[i]];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    A[i] = P[i];
```

If you're not allowed to modify P, then you have to work a lot harder (and you also have to work a lot harder if the data type of A is not the same as, or compatible with, the type of P).

However, I fear this is a sleight-of-hand trick that doesn't really answer the question; it gets the job done, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, if an interview isn't the place for sleight of hand, I don't know what is.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A[4] = {0,4,-1,1000}
    P[4] = {1,0,3,2}
    int temp = arr2[0];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(temp = P[i];i<3;temp = P[temp])
        {
        if(temp >= i)
        {
            int data; 
            data = A[i];
            A[i] = A[temp];
            A[temp] = data;
            break;
        }
        }

    }
    _getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A[4] = {0,4,-1,1000}
    P[4] = {1,0,3,2}
    int temp = arr2[0];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(temp = P[i];i<3;temp = P[temp])
        {
        if(temp >= i)
        {
            int data; 
            data = A[i];
            A[i] = A[temp];
            A[temp] = data;
            break;
        }
        }

    }
    _getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It would be best to add some explanation or comments to your code to make it more understable.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified to calculate dest value

```
int main()
{
    int A[4] = {0,4,-1,1000};
    int P[4] = {3,0,1,2};
    int value = A[0], dest = P[0];

    for(int i=0; i<4-1;i++)
    {
      int count=0;
      dest = P[i];
      while(dest<i){ //if P[i] points to lower value, it got swapped with some other position. 
        dest = P[dest];
      }
      swap(&A[dest],&A[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could argue that it goes against the spirit of the question - but can use multiple stack instances (from a run-time perspective) of a single local variable (code perspective).  Being allowed to mutate P is just as uncertain, so, FWIW - a recursive answer...

```
template <int N>
void shuffle(int (&a)[N], int p[], int i = -1)
{
    if (++i < N)
    {
        int result = a[p[i]];
        shuffle(a, p, i);
        a[i] = result;
    }
}
```